# Why is webpack-dev-server throwing an error when I use --arg?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server

This is my script:

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js --arg devus"
```

In my old setup I used to do:

```
"dev": "node build/dev-server.js --arg dev"
```

How can I achieve the same (having the `--arg` dev thing) with `webpack-dev-server`?

This is the error:

```
Unknown argument: arg
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-phantom@1.0.0 dev: `webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js --arg devus`
```

Comment: @str Sorry, I forgot to add the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you described was possible with webpack 1.

As of webpack 2+ (and webpack-dev-server will pass the arguments to the webpack as is) **passing the custom arguments can be done only by prefixing** the arguments with `env.`:

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js --env.arg devus"
```

However your script will not work as is, you would need to adapt it to use `env` property inside of your webpack configuration.

In other words this is how your config should look like

```
module.exports = env => {
  console.log(env);

  return {
    // your config heree
  }
};
```

See the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#environment-options)

Comment: Thanks, how should I get that argument in the js files? I used to do it like `const env = process.env.NODE_ENV`.